# Overlapping pod dependencies

Tags: swift, firebase, cocoapods

I am using cocoapods 0.39. I added Cocoa Touch Framework "MyFramework" as a separate target to my Swift project. The framework is using `Firebase` as a Cocoapod dependency. I am using MyFramework inside the the app. When I try to build the app I get multiple errors:

```
class … is implemented in both …/MyFramework.framework/MyFramework and …/MyApp.app/MyApp. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

I understand what this error is about, but I am not able to fix it. If I remove `Firebase` from MyApp target then I can't use MyFramework inside the app as it depends on it. It looks like a common problem, but unfortunately I can't make it work.

My Podfile looks like this:

```
use_frameworks!

target 'MyApp' do
    pod 'Firebase'
end

target 'MyAppTests' do

end

target 'MyFramework' do
    pod 'Firebase'
end

target 'MyFrameworkTests' do
    pod 'Firebase'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You are linking Firebase twice.

You can use `inherit! :search_patchs` directive in Podfile (requires Cocoapods 1.0 or higher) to let `MyApp` know about the dependencies without actually linking them:

```
use_frameworks!

target 'MyFramework' do
    pod 'Firebase'
    pod 'FirebaseAnalytics'

    target 'MyApp' do
        inherit! :search_paths

    end
end
```

This requires that you **explicitly declare dependencies** in your `Podfile` to make them available in `MyApp` target. For example, adding `pod 'Firebase'` won't make `using FirebaseAnalytics` available in your application.

---

You can also convert `MyFramework` to a CocoaPod dependency and let CocoaPods handle the dependencies for you. To do this, create a Podspec file for your framework, like this:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|

# Meta data
s.name         = "MyFramework"
s.version      = "1.0.0"
s.platform     = :ios
s.ios.deployment_target = '8.0'
s.summary      = "-"
s.homepage     = "-"
s.license      = { :type => "MIT" }
s.author       = { "Me" => "-" }
s.platform     = :ios
s.ios.deployment_target = '8.0'
s.source       = { :path => "MyFramework" }

# Source configuration
s.source_files  = "MyFramework/**/*.swift"
s.resources = "MyFramework/**/*.{png,jpeg,jpg,storyboard,xib,strings}"

s.requires_arc = true

# Dependencies

# Firebase for iOS
s.dependency 'Firebase', '~> 3.0'

end
```

Then, you can add a development dependency to `MyFramework` in your application `Podfile` and remove `Firebase` dependency:

```
target 'MyApp' do
    pod 'MyFramework', :path => '.'
end
```

Update `.` to the `MyFramework.podspec` location if needed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This time I don't want to use MyFramework as a CocoaPod. Can you please explain "post_install hook"?

Comment: @sash Explicitly declaring dependencies and adding `inherit! search_paths` makes headers available at compilation time. See my update for a `Podfile`-only solution.

Comment: FYI this answer is for Cocoapods 1.0.0 and above. For 0.39 you really wanna upgrade, but if you need to stay on 0.39 you wanna use `link_with`

Comment: @HugoTunius I should've made clearer that first option requires 0.39, thanks for pointing that out

Comment: Unfortunately the solution should be for 0.39. @HugoTunius could you please explain link_with solution? I tried it, but I still see errors/warnings.

Comment: @sash Using 0.39 works with no issues. Adding the pod dependency just to the Framework target allows me to use it in the application code and doesn't give any duplicated symbols error. Try cleaning the project and deleting `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` folder and try again.

Comment: Thanks for the help @redent84 . Do you mean Podfile as in the question and just to remove Firabese from MyApp target? If I do that, I can’t use MyFramework inside the app as it needs Firebase.